# C# post request programmatically to Form Based Authorization

Tags: c#

I am searching how to send username and passwd to form based authorization in C# console app. Login is like here: 
http://www.zoneedit.com/auth/

i find this:
http://www.daniweb.com/forums/thread188864.html

but it does not working for JS popup. Is any options to programatically login in html page with form based authorization?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The page you're looking at is actually not "Form Based Authorization", nor is it a Javascript pop-up. It's actually a window generated by your web browser for making an [authenticated HTTP request](https://web.archive.org/web/20211020134945/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/102605-1.aspx). You can verify this, if you wish, by using a tool like [Fiddler](http://www.fiddlertool.com/fiddler/) to examine the HTTP headers that are generated when you send a request to `zoneedit.com/auth`.

Basically what you need to do is: (translated from VB in the 4guys article)

```
var req = new WebClient();

var URL = "www.zoneedit.com/auth";
var Username = "username_goes_here";
var Password = "pasword_goes_here";

var credentialCache = new CredentialCache();
credentialCache.Add(new Uri(URL), "Basic", new NetworkCredential(Username, Password));

req.Credentials = credentialCache;

var results = System.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(req.DownloadData(URL));
```